# How to run webpack loaders on browser

Tags: webpack, babeljs, eslint

I want to know how to run my webpack loader chain in a browser environment.
I'm starting my exploration on this. Anyone who has tried this before can share their experiences and tips.

My thought process is this.

- I have a file with a custom type in my code base that goes through bunch of loaders to get bundled.
- This file contains an Object with data and functions
- I will be generating this object in browser memory.
- Essentially what webpack loaders (which export one single function on module.exports) do is convert one piece of string into another
- So for me to run loaders on browser - I need to take the functions corresponding to my loader chain.
- Convert my object as string maintaining functions. And run the functions one after the other.
- At the end eval the final output to get the definition

I'm beginning my exploration into this now. So, any help/thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What conversions are you actually trying to do? Many loaders are going to expect to be running in Node, so that could easily make this a no-go.

Comment: I have my own loader, which I'm sure will work on browser. And babel and eslint along with that.

Comment: You could already `require('babel-core')` in your own application to load Babel to bundle it up for client-side. There is no reason to use them via Webpack's loader system.

Comment: But I want to do that in the browser. I'm not doing this FOR client-side. I want to do it IN client-side.

Comment: `babel-core` is just a library, you could `require` it in your own code like any other library you's use on the client side.

Comment: There is a library called `babel-standalone` that is made for the client side. I'm gonna use that.

Comment: That's certainly an option too. `babel-standalone` is `babel-core` and some presets bundled with webpack for you, so it gets you the same thing.